# Best solution to get value of fields from different Entitys

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

let's say for example that I got 2 Entities:

```
@Entity(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserDetail userDetail;
}



@Entity
public class UserDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_detail_id")
    private Long id;
    private String city;
    private int age;
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;
```

And I have got Repository like this:

```
public interface UserQueryRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetail, Long>{

}
```

How can I get JSON result like:
{
username: value
city: value
}

I tryed to make something like:

```
value = "SELECT users.username, user_detail.city, user_detail.age, user_detail.user_user_id from users INNER JOIN user_detail ON users.user_id = user_detail.user_user_id ", nativeQuery =true
```

But how can I put result to List?

Other Idea :

```
   @Query("SELECT new pl.createcompetition.model.tomp(e.username) FROM users e WHERE e.userDetail.city=?1")
    List<tomp> findAllByCity(String city);
```

(I can make other class "tomp" with variable:
username, city. But what if I will have many fields and entity ?

The thing is that i need some solution which one I will be able to use with many Entity and Fields(when I will want to get different data from them)

Please help guys.

Comment: Taking into account your tables are quite related, you can choose another aproach and use only one entity. An example about how to do it https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/ Then you can use Spring Jpa repositories to get "whole information" or projections (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to get a subset of properties

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement a `@Service` if I were you, not a repository, and implement a method utilizing `UserRepository`'s and `UserDetailsRepository`'s methods.

Comment: Do you mean return Values Per Entity and then sum them up to One Map ?

Comment: Well, you can create a POJO and in your service instantiate a new one like this: `Combined combined = new Combined(userRepository.getUsername(), userDetailsRepository.getCity()`. Then just map it to JSON with `Jackson ObjectMapper` like this: `String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(combined);`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using spring-data you can make use of projections.
Projections are a way of controlling what and how data is returned from a spring-data query.

On your repository, just change the return type to an interface, containing the fields that you need

```
public interface UserQueryRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetail, Long>{

List<UserDetailProjection> findAll()
```

and then declare your projection `UserDetailProjection` with the fields that you need (following the pojo convention)

```
public interface UserDetailProjection{
public String getUsername();

public String getCity();

@Value("#entity.name")
public String getOtherEntityName()
}
```

If you need references to other entities or even computed values you can use the template I wrote on the last line. See more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#2-open-projections)

LE:
The same repository method could also return another projection on your demand.
for example you could have

```
public interface UserQueryRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetail, Long>{

[1] List<UserDetailProjection> findAll()
[2] List<ExtendedUserDetailProjection> findAll()
```

Comment: Does it mean that everytime for different values I will have to make new UserDetailProjection ? For example 
if I add in UserDetailProjection -     public String getcompetition_name();
But I won't select value in Query then as Result I'm gonna get null is there any good way to fix it ?

Comment: No just add new fields/values to the projection. I wanted to point out that you can have different projections

Comment: Yes, but It won't be comfortable when i will have like 20 fields and 10 combinations Or i'm wrong and I can fix it ? Because as i said if I give 2 values to projection with 3 fields then one field gonna return null

Comment: please give a specific example, combinations/order do not matter in this case